# Google Directions Only, in pop-up window

Tags: javascript, user-interface, google-maps-api-3

Got my google maps stuff up and running driving direction etc was quite pleased with it given I am a first time web developer. 
Just one problem, when I showed it to the client (boss) he liked it but wanted the directions to appear as they are but in a pop-up not a separate tab.
Basically keep the map as is and display the routing info in a pop up window when "show route" is pressed
I've managed to get hold of all the routing info and display it in a moveable div but this isn’t what he wants.
So do does anybody I know of away of including just the directions
 stuff in a separate pop up window? or a tutorial on the topic? 
He wants to see it ASAP so I'm kind of up against it and any help would be really appreciated thanks all.

**Update:** As per dr Molles suggestions Have hidden the original div containing the information and tried to add it into the pop up

using the following code :

```
enter code herefunction directionsWindow () {
            // get the div containing the direction information from the google
            // maps direction service
            var divToShow=document.getElementById('directions');
            // store the returned div in a variable
            var htmlToDisplay = document.getElementById('directions').innerHTML
            // get the html contained in the div and store it in a variable

            win=window.open('about:blank','instructions','width=1000,height=1000');
            // open a new window
            doc=win.document;
            // create a new div
            var divToDisplay = doc.createElement('div');
            // set its id to directions
            divToDisplay.id = "directions";
            // set its html to that of the div in the parent document
            divToDisplay.innerHTML = htmlToDisplay;
            // append the div to the window
            doc.body.appendChild(divToDisplay);
            doc.open();
            doc.close();
        }
```

but this does'nt seem to work as htmlToDisplay is empty, even though i know the div exists and has content (I can see it for a start).
Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 0):

Open a window and write the instructions into the document:

```
win=window.open('about:blank','instructions','width=300,height=200');
doc=win.document;
doc.open();
doc.write('<div id="instructions">instructions</div>');
doc.close();
//reference to the div inside the popup
//->doc.getElementById('instructions')
```

[window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open)
[document.write()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.write)

Comment: Thanks Dr molle, do you know of any way i can add a div to the window and then pass the content using something like directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("div_name"))?

Comment: To make this possible, the popup must be open and the div present when you call setPanel() -does it? However, It's possible when the popup is open, I've modified the code above.

Comment: Hmm that kinda works if I load the child page when I load the parent page all directions get shown fine, but if I call the child window function just before  directionsDisplay.setPanel(doc.getElementById("directions")); I only get the last set of directions (im display routes from a central location to several others) Ill try running it through firebug to see what its doing.

Comment: I think the best approach would be to use the panel in the main page, but in a hidden state. So you don't have to struggle with the timeline, you can always read the contents of the hidden panel and put them into the popup.

Answer (score 0):

Just to let people know I've managed to get my directions in a separate "window".
I had to use jquery to show and hide the div i was using to display the directions and then make it draggable again with jquery.
Works well now I can view each of the waypoints on the map and show alternate roots, which I couldn't manage using just a new pop up window window.