# html2canvas - error - object HTMLCanvasElement

Tags: javascript, php, html, html2canvas

I need to print the div using javascript..
The content of this div is barcode which is generated..
Using normal approach of printing div element doesn't work because the barcode image is generated by php file and doesn't appear in printing page.. so I decided to use `html2canvas` approach to 'render' the div and then print it..
here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="source" onClick="capture()"> Some content and img of barcode </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function capture() {
    html2canvas( [ document.getElementById('source') ], {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=1000');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Print Div:</title>');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write(canvas);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();

        return true;
}

    });
}
```

mywindow opens, but doesn't contain the content of div I need to print..
I get this error: `[object HTMLCanvasElement]`

Thanks for attention..

Comment: .getElementById('#source') try with hash tag, no spaces im sure 'my div'

Comment: What is `canvas` in your code?

Comment: canvas is image of rendered div

Comment: So is it DOM element? Be aware that `document.write(...)` expect `string`.

Comment: It is DOM element.. I tryed document.write(...) with simple string and it works in this case.. I understand that document.write is not correct.. But what should I use instead? Thanks for attention

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the `html2canvas` docs:

```
onrendered: function(canvas) {
   // canvas is the final rendered <canvas> element
}
```

`canvas` is a DOM element. You cannot `document.write` DOM elements (it's a string metthod), and the output `[HTMLCanvasElement]` is how JS converted the DOM element to a string (it's not an error). If the popup is on the same domain as the parent window, you should be able to do `mywindow.document.appendChild(canvas)`. [Else if it's not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084266/how-to-add-a-div-to-popup-window-in-javascript) a possible workaround is to, - in your `onrendered` callback -, do:

```
var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL();
mywindow.document.write('<img src="' + canvasData + '">');
```

Comment: Thank you, I just used `var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL();
mywindow.document.write('<img src="' + canvasData + '">');` Works perfectly ;)

Comment: this works great for me 