# Manupulate divs of Pop up window from external url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a gaming site in which Inventory Displays in Popup from a external url

[image]

I want to add a Button Dynamically in Right Hand Box circled as Shown . 
Or else I can do any Operation on Pop up window like making a div hidden , background color etc .

this is the Complete Code of Loading Popup from URL

```
<script>

    var page = "http://steamcommunity.com/id/Omnitored/inventory/#730";

    var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                   .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
                   .dialog({
                       autoOpen: false,
                       modal: true,
                       height: 500,
                       width: 1025,
                   });

    $("#Deposit").click(function () {
            $dialog.dialog('open');
        });


</script>
```

I have tried to manupulate some styles on master Layout and Page Layout , but it is not working

```
   <style>
        .view_inventory_page .inventory_page_right {

        visibility:hidden;
    }
    #active_inventory_page {

    }
    </style>
```

like these class are of a div of right hand Pop as in Image

Is there any option we can manipulate the the Pop up Layout generated from other URL ?
any Help would be appreciated

Edit : I have seen some posts

[How to add a div to popup window in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084266/how-to-add-a-div-to-popup-window-in-javascript)

which says

"Due to the same-origin-policy (and google.com is certainly not your domain), you won't be allowed to access the DOM of the other window.

If the popup is from the same domain, the return value of window.open will be a reference to the popup's window object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open

"

On different origin we cant manipulate DOMs .

Comment: some markups of working page or a link to the website might help

Comment: ok . edited ........

Comment: There is as you stated no way a web page can interact with a page from a different origin. You will need to read the foreign page with a proxy and object your code on the server or after serving it from your domain